How can I get nodemon to recgonise my custom .d.ts typings?
I'm importing an NPM package which doesn't have any typings, and so i've created a typings/app.d.ts file which has the following in it: declare module 'express-cache-ctrl';  which NodeJS seems happy with when running the application normally.
However I'm struggling to get this to work with nodemon.
My nodemon.json file contains this:
{
  "ignore": [".git"],
  "execMap": {
    "ts": "node --require ts-node/register"
  },
  "watch": ["src/"],
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "development"
  },
  "ext": "js,json,ts"
}

and I've got a debug task in my package.json file which has this: "debug": "nodemon --inspect src/app.ts" I've seen online that people say to add --files to your nodemon command, i.e. "nodemon --inspect --files src/app.ts", but that just gives me:
[nodemon] 3.1.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): src/**/*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,json,ts
[nodemon] starting `node --require ts-node/register --inspect --files src/app.ts`
/usr/bin/node: bad option: --files
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

So what can I do?
I'm using NodeJS v22.7.0 and Yarn 4.4.1. I'm also hoping the solution will still let me debug using VSCode (which up to this point, it's been doing). My VSCode launch.json configuration for debugging is this:
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "name": "nodemon",
      "preLaunchTask": "Build",
      "request": "launch",
      "restart": true,
      "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
      "runtimeArgs": ["debug"],
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "type": "node"
    }
  ]
}

and my tasks.json is:
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "build",
      "group": "build",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "label": "Build"
    },
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "debug",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "label": "Debug"
    },
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "lint",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "label": "Lint"
    }
  ]
}

my scripts section in package.json contains this:
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf ./build && tsc",
    "debug": "nodemon --inspect src/app.ts",
    "start": "node build/app.js",
    "lint": "eslint src/*.ts"
  },


What do you want to achive with the --files argument? nodemon has no --files option. If you want to specify the entry file, just run node --require ts-node/register --inspect src/app.ts

What i'm trying to achieve is attempting to solve my issue. And when I was searching for this kind of error, people were saying "just add --files" but obviously, that doesn't help me. Are you saying then that I can't run with nodemon at all?

@Marc I have just changed my debug task in my package.json file to node --require ts-node/register --inspect src/app.ts and this has no effect, i'm still getting the same error.

Your question is focused on a solution you found for a Typescript problem, but that solution makes no sense for what your original problem was. The error here is about that --files argument not being recognized. It's not clear how that related to typescript definition files, so perhaps revert your solution and focus on the original problem.
